# How to add string value to timestamp in C#

Tags: c#, string, timestamp, devexpress

i have textedit1.text it has a value 2 in my winform,..and then i have timedit called timePekerjaanStart value 04:00:00 . the case is i wanna addition between textedit1 and timePekerjaanStart ,i catch the result in timestamp called timePekerjaanEnd. so , i wanna get the result timePekerjaanEnd = textedit1 + timePekerjaanStart as like 2 + 04:00:00 = 06:00:00

Comment: Use [Int32.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [AddHours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @GrantWinney: It's quite clear that the OP means the [TimeEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsTimeEdittopic) class from DevExpress. The [Time](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsTimeEdit_Timetopic) property is used to get or set a [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so my above suggestion would solve the problem. Regarding AM/PM, that is as the Borg say: Irrelevant.

Comment: i have textedit1.text it has a value 2 in my winform,..and then i have timedit called timePekerjaanStart value 04:00:00 . the case is i wanna addition between textedit1 and timePekerjaanStart ,i catch the result in timestamp called timePekerjaanEnd. so , i wanna get the result timePekerjaanEnd = textedit1 + timePekerjaanStart as like 2 + 04:00:00 = 06:00:00 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not provided any attempts to solve it yourself but it's really quite straight forward:

```
var theHoursToAdd = int.Parse(textedit1.Text);  // Error handling needs to be added
var startTime = timePekerjaanStart.Time;
timePekerjaanEnd.Time = startTime.AddHours(theHoursToAdd);
```